# Euler's Method -Calculation of order without noticing to which number $\frac{e^i}{e^{i+1}}$ converges

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

We have the initial value problem $$\left\{\begin{matrix}
y'=y, 0 \leq t \leq 1, \\ 
y(0)=1
\end{matrix}\right.$$

for which the solution is $y(t)=e^t$.

Applying the Euler's Method we get the following:

$$h=\frac{1}{N} \\ t^n=nh \\  \\ y^{n+1}=y^n(1+h) \\ $$

$$ \\ y^0=1 \\y^1=1+h \\ y^2=(1+h)^2 \\ \dots \\ y^n=(1+h)^n$$

We calculate the approxiamtion of the solution at $t=1$, so $y^N$

$$\epsilon^N=y(t^N)-y^N=y(1)-y^N=e-(1+h)^N$$

So we get the following matrix:

$$\begin{matrix}
N & h & y^N &  \epsilon^N & \frac{ \epsilon^{i}}{ \epsilon^{i+1}}\\ 
- & - & - & - & -\\ 
1 & 1 & 2 & 0.71828 & \\ 
2 & 1/2 & 2.25 & 0.46828 & 1.53 \\ 
4 & 1/4 & 2.44141 & 0.27688 & 1.69 \\ 
8 & 1/8 & 2.56578 & 0.15250 & 1.82 \\ 
16 & 1/16 & 2.63793 & 0.08035 & 1.90 \\ 
32 & 1/32 & 2.67699 & 0.04129 & 1.95 \\
64 & 1/64 & 2.69734 & 0.02094 & 1.97 
\end{matrix}$$

By dividing the step $h$ by $2$, the error is also divided by $2$.

So the error is proportional to $h$.

$$\epsilon^n \approx O(h^a)$$

In our case: $a=1$.

We make as many steps, till we see that the quotient of an error to its previous one converges to $2$.

We are looking for the order $a$ in order to know which $h$ we have to take to have the desired accuracy.

But, if for example $\frac{ \epsilon^i}{ \epsilon^{i+1}}$ would converge to $3$ , what would be the order $a$?

Also, in this case we find $a$ by making as many steps as possible to see that $\frac{ \epsilon^i}{\epsilon^{i+1}}$ converges to $2$.

If we don't notice to which number  $\frac{ \epsilon^i}{ \epsilon^{i+1}}$ converges, how can we calculate $a$?

Comment: @Amzoti The last $\frac{e^i}{e^{i+1}}$ is calculated as follows:

$$\frac{0.04129}{0.02094}=1.97182425 \dots$$

Comment: The first quotient is equal to $\frac{e_1}{e_2}$, the second to $\frac{e_2}{e_4}$, the third to $\frac{e_4}{e_8}$  and so on.. I calculate them in order to find the relation between $h$ and $e^n$. @Amzoti

Comment: @Amzoti Like that, we conclude that dividing $h$ by $2$, the error is also divided by $2$.

Answer (score 0):

If for dyadic powers $f(2^n)=3^n=2^{n\cdot\log_2(3)}$ then the generalization or interpolation is $f(n)=n^{\log_2(3)}$.

See the infamous master theorem of computer science.